# How to do twig calculation for mathematical operation in view

Tags: views, theming

I have two fields.
Marks obtained as `field_marks_obtained`
Total Marks as `field_total_marks`
Now I have added both in view and added a custom text in which i am writing custom twig to output the percentage.
I have tried with

`{{ field_marks_obtained }}` which gives me output as 359.00

`{{ field_marks_obtained + field_total_marks}}` giving result as 2.

`{{ field_marks_obtained * field_total_marks}}` giving result as 1

How can i do arithmetic operation with twig. I have also tried with

`{% set marks = field_marks_obtained * 1 %}{{ marks }}` which also returns 1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`{% set marks = field_marks_obtained|trim %}`

`{% set total = field_total_marks|trim %}`

You can do any complex calculation in twig like this.

`{{ (marks/total)*100 }}`

Comment: The |trim are important here.

Answer (score 1):

Use raw database values for calculation. Most times rendered output doesn't work, because it contains strings or render arrays, not numbers.

I think you are referring to field rewriting in the Views fields UI, then open REPLACEMENTS PATTERN and you'll find this information:

> You must add some additional fields to this display before using this
>   field. These fields may be marked as Exclude from display if you
>   prefer. Note that due to rendering order, you cannot use fields that
>   come after this field; if you need a field not listed here, rearrange
>   your fields.
>
> The following replacement tokens are available for this field. Note
>   that due to rendering order, you cannot use fields that come after
>   this field; if you need a field not listed here, rearrange your
>   fields.
>
> - {{ field_number }} == Number
> - {{ field_number__value }} == Raw value

So you need to add `__value` to each field name.

Comment: No there is no raw value for replacement pattern.

Comment: Can you provide more details?

Answer (score -1):

In Drupal view, below solution worked for me

{% set wgt = weight | trim %}
{% set qty = quantity | trim %}
{{ wgt*qty }}