# How can I compare a view token with a string?

Tags: 8

I have a view token
{{ field_category }} == Content: Category
I need a condition like
if field category == "Foo & Bar"
do something
else
do something

I wrote code

```
         {% if field_category == "Foo & Bar" %}

             string1            
         {% else %}
        
            string 2
        
        {% endif %}
```

But it always goes for the else part even if the token value is "Foo & Bar"

Please help to find a solution

Comment: This depends on the field type. If it is a text field storing string values then add `__value` to the token or for more complex fields you can try to render and trim the field. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/252795/how-to-do-twig-calculation-for-mathematical-operation-in-view

Comment: It works Thankyou

Answer (score 3):

> But it always goes for the else part even if the token value is "Foo &
> Bar"

This is because by default Views adds classes to your field:

[image]

Which means `field_category` is actually equal to `<div class="some-class">Foo & Bar</div>`

and since `<div class="some-class">Foo & Bar</div>` is not equal to `Foo & Bar` your conditional always goes to the else.

If you uncheck the "Add default classes" in your category field settings, your conditional should work now. Unless... your field is linking to something so it would still be `<a href="/some-url">Foo & Bar</a>` and not equal.

As 4k4 commented, you can instead use `field_category__value` to get the raw value and not have to uncheck the "Add default classes".

Comment: Thanks for the reply